# AWS Lambda read PDF from local directory | Nodejs

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am trying to send a **GMAIL** message containing a **PDF** file (I am using **nodemailer** for this).
The error is generated when reading the PDF file with path (native dependency of node); The error that returns is a 500 Server Error.

```
module.exports.get_boletin = async (event) => {

const { wrapedSendMail } = require('./helpers/sendPromise');
const path = require('path');

const { email } = JSON.parse(event.body);

if(!email) {
  return {
    statusCode: 400,
    body: JSON.stringify({
    ok: false,
    detail: 'Email is required'
    })
  };
}

const mailOptions = {
  to: email,
  from: "example@gmail.com",
  subject: `any_msg`,
  attachments: [
    {
      filename: `file.pdf`,
      path: path.join(__dirname, `file.pdf`),
      contentType: 'application/pdf',
    },
   ],
  }

 const _send = await wrapedSendMail(mailOptions)

 if(_send){
   return {
     statusCode: 200,
     body: JSON.stringify({
     ok: true,
     detail: 'Mensaje enviado correctamente.',
     event: JSON.parse(event.body)
   })
  }
 } else {
    return {
      statusCode: 500,
      body: JSON.stringify({
      ok: false,
      detail: 'Error al enviar el mensaje.',
      event: JSON.parse(event.body)
    })
  }
 }
};
```

This piece of code is the one that generates the error

```
attachments: [
    {
      filename: `file.pdf`,
      path: path.join(__dirname, `file.pdf`),
      contentType: 'application/pdf',
    },
   ]
```

I tried locally and in an EC2 instance, this works normally the error is only generated in Lambda

Comment: Check the cloudwatch to see the error detail.

Comment: I think the problem is related to the AWS Lambda limit. You don't have access while running to your lambda function only to the /tmp directory. Try modifying you code to save and read your pdf file from the /tmp directory

Comment: @GhamguiKhaled that's not correct. You have read access to the entire environment. You only have **write** access to `/tmp`. The doesn't appear to be any disk write operation happening in the posted code, so that shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Are you sure the PDF file is included in the Lambda function's deployment? You might want to log `__dirname` to make sure it is what you expect it to be when running in the Lambda environment. As mentioned above, `500` responses just mean something happened on the server, and you need to go check the actual server logs to see what the error is. Without the actual error message all anyone can do is guess what your issue is.